# Boost Spirit: How to print only "parsed"?

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit

I want to print only the found string, without the open and end characters of boost spirits's confix_p.

So the code looks like this:

```
confix_p( ch_p('"'), *c_escape_ch_p, ch_p('"') )
```

How can i now just output the found *c_escape_ch_p* string without the *"* open/end chars?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is it "classic Spirit"? If it's not some 10-years old legacy code, it's worth moving to a modern Spirit version.

Comment: How can i find out? So i just want to get rid of the quotes. I am using this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/libs/spirit/doc/confix.html

Comment: It's extremely outdated. Current boost version is 1.57. Spirit v2 is in Boost since 1.37.

Comment: also, your code doesn't print anything. Make a SSCCE and I'll help